# How to use new Feature Hooks in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I just read about the react's new feature hooks.[Read about hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html?no-cache=1)
but i can't able to use it.
it gives me error.

I am currently using version 16.6.0

Finally i got Understand the hooks.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Fun = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    );}

 export default Fun;
```

I imported as Fun and used as  in my app.js file

The mistake i made is i did't install React v16.7.0-alpha so i installed using npm add react@next react-dom@next.

Thank you

Comment: As far is I know, React Hooks moved into 16.7.0-alpha.2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Hooks are released as a part of version 16.8.0 and you can use it by installing React and React-dom 16.8.0

run

```
yarn install react@16.8.0 react-dom@16.8.0
```

to install. In order to upgrade react to latest version

```
yarn upgrade react react-dom
```

---

Hooks aren't present in version 16.6.0, but are a proposal for version 16.7.0. You can however use `16.7.0-alpha.0` alpha version of React to test them

In order to use this install the above version using

```
yarn add react@next react-dom@next
```

Make sure that you install both `react` and `react-dom` or else your would get warning like

> TypeError: Object(…) is not a function” error when trying to use react
>   hooks (alpha)

Comment: but i getting the error  Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.   how to use this ?

Comment: @Ram, I suggest you create a question with specific details about your error and also provide the relevant code

Comment: Adding `react-dom` was the key for me.  The react docs at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html didn't mention that.  Pretty frustrating.

Comment: @Farid You need to make use of the same version of react and react-dom always.

Comment: I'm getting the same TypeError as above, however, my dependencies have the correct Alpha versions.  Has anyone experienced this?  I have a different project that uses them without issue and I'm trying to go about config the same way but cannot get past this error as soon as I try to use the new API.

Comment: @adam.shaleen do you use the same version for react and react-dom. Also more details on your problem would help

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Apologies, I should have responded to my post.  I needed to update to V alpha-2 and that solved my issues when attempting to use the hooks API.  Thank you for reaching out.