# React Hooks issues in React 16.7 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm running the latest version of React and I'm getting this error
[image]
I have a simple Component using React Hooks as you can see here :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AppFunction = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const incrementCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Count:{count} </h1>
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AppFunction;
```

Everything i've found about it on stack overflow says to upgrade the libraries but I have the latest version (16.7.0) and have tried the alpha version with no luck , what am i doing wrong?

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
```

Comment: What exact statement that error is about?

Comment: I edited with a screen shot of the error

Comment: I'm not sure that line can trigger such an error :-S

Comment: I console.log useState and it comes out undefined, so its not getting imported right or something

Comment: Are you sure you're running react v16.7?

Comment: Yeah, i edited again with the package.json, i've also tried the alpha versions

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json && npm install`?

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: What does that "Didn't work" mean?

Comment: I tried running that code in the terminal and I am getting the same error

Comment: Same issue here. It just happened recently. There doesn't appear to be a useState function being exported. It returns as undefined on alpha2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Hooks are now release as part of React v16.8.0. You can use hooks by upgrading your react version

See the **[docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)** for more details on the APIs

---

React 16.7.0 Doesn't contain hooks.

As per the [React blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/12/19/react-v-16-7.html)

> Our latest release includes an important performance bugfix for
>   React.lazy. Although there are no API changes, we’re releasing it as a
>   minor instead of a patch.

In order to run hooks in your code, refer [How to use new Feature Hooks in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009302/how-to-use-new-feature-hooks-in-react/53009407#53009407)

Comment: Thanks I tried the alpha versions before, but it was alpha.0, alpha.2 is now working

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use the following in package.json but do not work.

```
"react": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
"react-dom": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
```

What worked is the following

```
"react": "next",
"react-dom": "next",
```

EDIT

React version v16.8.0 has Hooks inside. Use that.

Answer (score 0):

edit package.json

```
"react": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
"react-dom": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
"react-router-dom": "4.4.0-beta.6",
```

and run `yarn`

The react released 16.7.0, but there are no react hooks. If you use '^react@16.7.0-alpha.2', remove yarn.lock, it will install react@16.7.0. So you must delete '^' and use 'react@16.7.0-alpha.2'.