# I am using react useState hook, but its not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I just read about the react's new feature hooks.Read about hooks but i can't able to use it. it gives me

Comment: What does it give? The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . In case there's an error, it should present . See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009302/how-to-use-new-feature-hooks-in-react/53009407#53009407

Answer (score 1):

Update your react version in your package.json to "16.7.0-alpha.2" like so:

```
"react": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
"react-dom": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
```

React hooks needs the latest versions of react to work !!

Answer (score 1):

That's because react-hooks are not a official version yet. It is experimental therefore you have to install packages explicitly.

You can install required versions using these commands:

```
npm install react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.2 
npm install react@16.7.0-alpha.2
```

If you have them installed, then please edit your question and post the code sample.